# How to get all HTTP Methods in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, http

I need to develop a method which returns all HTTP Methods in a certain format of an object.

Is there a method which returns all the HTTP methods as a list in NodeJS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a method but an string array constant is readily available from the `http` module:

```
 const http = require('http')

 console.log(http.METHODS)
```

Source: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_methods

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in [NodeJS.dev](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-http-module)

```
const methods = require('http').METHODS;
methods.length
```

the methods object have all the HTTP methods now you can loop